# Set full URL to Image source next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

In next.js `<Image` source is setting source URL with just `<img src="/_next/image...."`, but I want `<Image` source to set source URL with `<img src="https://example.com/_next/image..."` ( including domain ).

Reproducible Code:

```
use Image from "next/image";

// After importing the above, simply use the following:

<Image src={`/img/example.png`} />
```

Rendered Code is:

```
<img alt="test" sizes="100vw" srcset="/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=640&amp;q=75 640w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=750&amp;q=75 750w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=828&amp;q=75 828w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=1080&amp;q=75 1080w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=1200&amp;q=75 1200w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=1920&amp;q=75 1920w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=2048&amp;q=75 2048w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75 3840w" src="/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fexample.png&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75" decoding="async" data-nimg="fill" loading="lazy" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; color: transparent;">
```

So, if you see above, all the path starts with `/_next/image....`, but I want it to be `https://example.com/_next/image...` full URL of the host.

Do we have any settings in next.js or hack around to accomplish them?

Thanks

We tried googling and finding source relevant settings, but could not find any.

Comment: How are you calling `<Image`? Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AhmedSbai - Example added above

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your loader for `<Image>` https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the next/image. I want to use it, but want to have a full URL instead of `/_next/image/....`

Comment: @RSharma why would you use next/image if you don't want to use a cached image?

Comment: Where did I mention I don't want to use the cached images? In the whole page, only your response includes "cache", I have not even mentioned the word. I definitely want to use next/image, but want next.js to print full path of URL instead of providing relative URL in src tag. Please see update on questions with relevant code example

Comment: @RSharma you yourself don't want /_next/image/ in the URL, which means you don't want to use cached images. Cached images can only be obtained from this url

Comment: I think there is a language barrier. I said, I want `/_next/image` but with full URL `http://example.com/_next/image`

Comment: Sorry, you need to use your loader https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader